# How can I fix this error at creating new page?

Tags: c#, android, ios, xaml, xamarin

I have a Xamarin.Forms Project.

In this project I already had a blank page but I added a new one, is when the error started showing.

The errors that show are:

```
Error XLS0414
The type 'ContentPage' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.
TaskX.Android New.xaml
1 

Error XLS0414  The type 'StackLayout' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.
TaskX.Android New.xaml
10
```

**EDIT**
This is the code:

```
<ContentPage>
    x:Class="TaskX.New"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TaskX"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"

    <StackLayout>

    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered this problem a while ago. Try these steps below, they worked for me.

1. Remove Xamarin.Forms and Re-Install Xamarin.forms.
2. Update all your Nugets packages.
3. Clean and Build solution.

**If the problem persists :**

1. Restart your Visual Studio and/or your PC.
2. Make sure your Visual Studio is up-to-date and you do not have any pending windows updates to do.
3. Repair Visual Studio.
4. You can also clear NuGet cache from 'C:\Users{User}\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache'

Comment: And How Can I Clean The Cache?

Comment: Navigate under the link I provided in the answer above.
Delete all folders. Your packages will be re-downloaded.

Comment: Check this link for further explanation.
https://montemagno.com/cleanup-up-space-xamarin-dev-machine/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

All the referencing will be inside `<contentPage>` tag.

```
<ContentPage
   x:Class="TaskX.New"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:local="using:TaskX"
   xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
   xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
   mc:Ignorable="d">

   <StackLayout>

   </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```