# Error in Xamarin Forms app.xaml with AppThemeColor

Tags: xamarin.forms

I just updated all of my nuget packages, which updated my Xamarin Forms packaged.  It also updated my 'androidX packages.

I am getting the following errors:
Error: XLS0414: The type 'AppThemeColor' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

XamlC error XFC0000: Cannot resolve type "AppThemeColor".

I have update my nuget packages.  I have verified that Xamarin.Forms is referenced in the net standard project.  Any ideas as to what is causing this error?

TIA.

Comment: Try delete bin/obj folders

Comment: An error like this has been reported here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51600664/how-can-i-fix-this-error-at-creating-new-page

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/11099

Comment: @magicandre1981 I think that is exactly the issue.  Thank you.

Comment: For the moment, I have downgraded my XF to 4.6.x.

Comment: as written in the link, Microsoft renamed the experimental API in 4.6 SR4. You need to change your code. I also wait until Theme API is final and experimental flag for theming is removed

Answer (score 0):

If you updated to 4.7.0, the official workaround is to downgrade to 4.6.x.
I get this error all the time now but the projects still build, so I ignore it.

I'm sure it will be fixed soon.

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/11101